# Functionals defined on curves

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, geometric-topology

I am looking for classical (real) functionals defined on rectifiable curves (neither necessarily simple nor closed) in either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$.

There's length, turning number, total curvature, mean curvature, ... What else?

This question is quite loosely stated, I'm sorry, but I'm just in a pre-hunting phase, looking for (real) numbers associated to curves :)

Thanks!

Comment: Energy is pretty classical, but very similar to length though.